# pattern the string with brackets with python

Tags: python

For example,

```
a = ['a','d','q','q(a)','dfo','qwfdf','df(r)','dfsdfp(o)']
```

This is the list with serveral strings. I want to pattern the strings which contains brackets.

Comment: What does 'pattern the strings' mean?

Comment: what does **`pattern`**  means exactly ?

Comment: and the other interesting thing is you don't have bracket in your example :D

Comment: If you are looking for strings which having "(" or ")" you can use this following code. `print [each for each in a if "(" in each or ")" in each]`. I am printing, you can save to one variable and use further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use regular expressions

```
        import re

        a = ['a','d','q','q(a)','dfo','qwfdf','df(r)','dfsdfp(o)']

        found = []

        p = re.compile('\(.*\)')
        for item in a:
            m = re.search(p,str(item))
            if m:
                found.append(item)

        found
```

This returns:

```
        ['q(a)', 'df(r)', 'dfsdfp(o)']
```